# FFmpeg - how to adjust video duration to sound duration if sound is longer, possible without re-encoding it with mp3 file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a problem. I have recorded my videos separately, and then added sound to it. Sometimes, sound is longer or less in duration compared to video duration. Usually sound is longer, sometimes around 20 seconds. **To me, when running on my PC through flv or some Windows Media player, that is not problem, since after video is over, last capture of video stays displayed (like an image), and sounds is still executing, and video ends after sound is over**. So everything is ok at my PC when running it like .flv or .mp4 file. But, when I upload that on Google drive or some other place on web (that is, when I run it in my browser for viewing after upload), I see **my video is cutted to the lenght of the video duration (so my sound is cutted)**. I understand that this is because of different duration sizes of sound and video.

Now **I need a command with ffmpeg that can make my video to be extened to my sound duration**. I would like not to reencode my videos with sound again (in sense that I would need to put my mp3 file in ffmpeg command) if I don't need (since I have many videos and sound is already inserted in them), but just to reencode video with some ffmpeg command.

I have watched this (not sure at the momen if this would even help me): 
https://superuser.com/questions/801547/ffmpeg-add-audio-but-keep-video-length-the-same-not-shortest

But with this approach, you have to reencode video with sound (mp3 or similar) file first.

Can it be done, and what would be command, or commands for it? 
(Edit: And if only way is to re-encode it with mp3 file, what would be command for it?)

**Edit: I don't want to cut my sound, I need to hold last frame till my sound is over. Currently last frame is holded only when viewing on my PC, when I upload that, clip is cutted immediately when video stops.**

Comment: can you upload an example file?

Comment: you can use `-t` or  `-shortest` options.

Comment: incBrain, I don't know what example you want? I can give you screenshot of video, that doesen't make sense to me you can figure some of it? Just imagine currently I have video that plays some seconds (till sound expires) after video ends. After upload, when watching throught web browser, sound is cutted when video ends).

Comment: Mitra M, can you show on example if it doesen't include sound file in command? I would prefer to re-encode without including sound file in ffmpeg command.

Comment: [Answered at video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/23083). Please avoid crossposting the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: LordNeckbeard ok, but neither there, neither here it is answered correctly..